# How do i blacklist files from opening? on windows? explorer or firefox?

Tags: virus

Is there a way i can blacklist multiple files? right now i am thinking exe, msi and bat. I need a list of dangerous file extension (one i found online had rtf and mp3 on it WTF, exploitable files does not count bc that is everything).

How can i prevent windows explorer from executing these files? I know how to prevent these files from being extracted via winrar but i dont know how to stop it from firefox and explorer.

-edit- i'll make sure the account isnt an admin XP account. I am doing a favour to the owner who doesnt know anything about computers and needs to install the occasional app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the corporate environment I've seen [Faronics Anti-Executable](http://www.faronics.com/html/AntiExec.asp) used a fair bit. Faronics products (best known for deep freeze) are fairly popular with the bigger corporations but you can also buy single licenses for a decent price. You can create whitelists for file types you want to allow and have the rest denied. It uses hashes as well which can be used to keep programs off the system entirely.

For a free alternative there is [System Safety Monitor](http://download.cnet.com/System-Safety-Monitor-Free-Edition/3000-2098_4-10556556.html), which has a lot less features, but it might suit your needs.

Anti-Executable would be my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows' builtin security policies. See [Description of the Software Restriction Policies in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310791).